# jsoup output encoding issue

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using JSoup to parse a gb2312 charset page:
http://vars.sinaapp.com/u/t/jsoup_output_encoding_issue.html

source code:

```
String testURL="http://vars.sinaapp.com/u/t/jsoup_output_encoding_issue.html";
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(testURL).get();          
System.out.println(
    doc.select("div").html()
);
```

this gives the following output:

```
1:? 2:&#65533; 3:&#65533; 4:&#8212;
```

I want to get same with page source code:

```
1:· 2:慒 3:啰 4:&mdash;
```

Is there any way to do this?‎

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting[`doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html) or changing the output [charset](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#charset%28java.lang.String%29) before printing.

See also the (paltry) [documentation for `EscapeMode`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Entities.EscapeMode.html).

Comment: thanks for help,I'm tried other charsets , `EscapeMode.xhtml` and `prettyPrint(false)`, the output is the same

Comment: @Zenofo: bummer =(  Consider updating your question with a few things you've tried, this might improve the quality of other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding as "MS932" or "SHIFT-JIS".This will solve your problem.
you can also read the charset type of the html page  and set while parsing the file.